# Run process on any one Pod in the Kubernetes deployment

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, akka

I have an application that runs on multiple pods and scales out when traffic increases. One of the features of the application is that "It picks messages from Kafka and triggers email".

When multiple pods are running, all of them trigger the email as all pods are supposed to pick up the msg as per the design.

How can I restrict the email functionality to work on any one of the pods at a time?

Cluster - EKS , Programming language - Scala AKKA

Comment: When a consumer processes a message, the message is not removed from its topic. Instead, consumers can choose from several ways of letting Kafka know which messages have been processed. This process is known as committing the offset. So once you get the message from list , right away you need to commit offset so that otehr consumers will get the following messages

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "restrict the email functionality to work on any one of the pods at a time"?

Comment: @LeviRamsey that means email triggering function is present on all the pods but only one pod should execute it.

Comment: @Pranav If only one of the pods trigger the email, what does others do? Using consumer groups ensures that some emails are triggered by pod1, pod *x* and so on, thus sharing the workload. This way, the same email will not be triggered by multiple pods.

Comment: @JavaTechnical the problem is that pods also provide live data on web socket connection to front end application and the front end app connects to any one pod. So data from kafka should be picked up by all pods. actually the same data is pushed via email also in a consolidated form,

Comment: @Pranav, just to be sure, you want multiple pods consuming from Kafka, a single pod to send email, and the data read from Kafka to be distributed to all nodes (by which I mean, you need every message to reach every node at least once)?  If that's the case, why exactly do you want multiple pods: there'd be zero performance benefit (and in fact quite a performance cost) over a single pod?

Comment: The only benefit I can see for multiple pods would be for high availability (being able to instantly failover to a backup pod) with possibly better performance than spinning up a new pod.

Comment: (of course, if by "data from Kafka should be picked up by all pods", you mean that each message from Kafka is going to be processed into zero or more state updates and those state updates distributed to all the pods, that's very different, depending on how intensive the processing is)

Answer (score 3):

> How can I restrict the email functionality to work on any one of the
> pods at a time?

**In short:** Use same consumer group for all the pods that trigger the email.
Usually, workloads are categorized into groups based on the work they do. Members of the same group share workload amongst themselves.

You could certainly have given Kafka consumer configurations like `bootstrap.servers` etc to your pods. In that configuration, give a property with name `group.id` to some value like `email-trigger-group` for example and then the workload will be shared as you would expect.

You could have used *labels* for your pods that trigger email. You can use the same label value for your consumer `group.id` for all of your pods.

---

We can divide the problem into two sub-problems:

**1. Trigger email**

This workload can be shared by multiple consumers in the group.

**2. Answer requests to the frontend**

Use manual `consumer.assign()` for the whole topic (all partitions).

The frontend would specify the *timestamp* from where it would want new messages from i.e. messages with timestamps `>` this timestamp will be retrieved from *all partitions* of the topic. To do this use `consumer.offsetsForTimes()` to get the timestamps, poll and send the messages as response.

```java
List<TopicPartition> topicPartitions = consumer.partitionsFor("your_topic").stream().map(partitionInfo -> new TopicPartition(partitionInfo.topic(), partitionInfo.partition()).toList();
consumer.assign(topicPartitions);

// Populate the map
Map<TopicPartition, Long> partitionTimestamp = new LinkedHashMap<>();

// Add the same timestamp received from frontend for all partitions
topicPartitions.forEach(topicPartition -> partitionTimestamp.put(topicPartition, timestampFromFrontend));

// Get the offsets and seek
Map<TopicPartition,OffsetAndTimestamp> offsetsForTimes = consumer.offsetsForTimes(offsetsForTimestamp);

// Seek to the offsets
offsetsForTimes.forEach( (tp, oft) -> consumer.seek(tp, oft.offset()) );

// Poll and return
consumer.poll();
```

Comment: the problem is that pods also provide live data on web socket connection to front end application and the front end app connects to any one pod. So data from kafka should be picked up by all pods.

Comment: @Pranav So any pod to which the frontend connects has to provide messages from all the partitions till that time (regardless of which partitions it got assigned to). isn't it?

Comment: Use `consumer.assign()` rather than `subscribe()` for answering frontend requests and ask the frontend to give the timestamp of its last consumed message from where it would want new messages. Just do a seek to the offset of all the partitions identified by that timestamp using `offsetForTimes()`, poll and return the response.

Comment: @JavaTechnical Could you please help me on it https://stackoverflow.com/q/75756053/3946958

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Kafka you can use partitions.

For each topic there can be multiple partitions. These partitions are shared between consumers.

For example:

```
Email Topic: Partitions[0,1,2,3,4,5]

Email Consumer Group:
   Consumer 1: Partitions[0,3]
   Consumer 2: Partitions[1,4]
   Consumer 3: Partitions[2,5]

On Scale Up Event:
   Consumer 1: Partitions[0]
   Consumer 2: Partitions[1]
   Consumer 3: Partitions[2,5]
   Consumer 4: Partitions[3]
   Consumer 5: Partitions[4]

On Scale Down Event:
   Consumer 1: Partitions[0,2,4]
   Consumer 2: Partitions[1,3,5]
```

This way only one consumer in particular group will consume message.

Comment: i need all pods to receive all data since they have some other functionality also apart from the email part

Comment: Email group is partitioned so they share the load. You can add other groups to same topic. Each group will receive the same topic data. Rest depends on how you want to partition.