# How to configure microservice's each pods/process of the Kubernetes deployment with different kafka topic?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

In our application there are multiple cosumer of different kafka topics like Cosumer C1 ,Cosumer C2 ,Cosumer C3 ,Cosumer C4 ,Cosumer C5 with their different kafka topic like topic 1 , topic 2 , topic 3 , topic 4 and topic 5. Means their is pair of each producer and consumer . Their is not any issue when i runs this all on the single microservice 's POD/process of Kubernetes.

My question is that i want to create the 5 PODS with each pod consists the Cosumer - Producer from their topic like below :- 
POD 1 :- Cosumer 1 - Topic 1 
POD 2 :- Cosumer 2 - Topic 2 
POD 3 :- Cosumer 3 - Topic 3 
POD 4 :- Cosumer 4 - Topic 4 
POD 5 :- Cosumer 5 - Topic 5

Means each POD/Process has only one topic , they should not be dependent to one another.

Is their configuration require for this one , please help me on it. Thanks

Comment: Why do you want different topics for each pod? Have you considered partitioning one topic? The number of partitions can be the same as the number of consumers. In that case, if they are part of the same consumer group, the same message would be read by only one consumer from that group. Check this [link](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/kafka-the-definitive/9781491936153/ch04.html) for more info.

Comment: You've been commenting on the very similar [how to configure each pods/process consume different kafka topic partition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69130578/how-to-configure-each-pods-process-consume-different-kafka-topic-partition) which recently got a StatefulSet-based answer.  I probably would not worry much about which specific pod is handling which specific topic or partition; as @birca123 suggests, use a single topic and make sure you have at least as many partitions as replicas, and Kafka will manage partition assignment for you.

Comment: Every consumer in one group should be oblivious of partition number. Treat all partitions equal will allow you to scale better, and your code easier to understand. Similarly, replicas of a StatefulSet/Deployment in k8s should all be treated the same way, even if you use the downward API to extract k8s resource information into your app, you shouldn't really couple that to kafka configuration beyond the client.id; the group.id can be an environment variable shared over all replicas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run 5 containers in one pod, passing each topic name as an environment variable to the containers.

If you want all containers to be the same, except for the topic name, you can write a Helm template with a loop over the topics for each container

For example, start with a values file like this

```
application:
  image: myapp
  tag: latest

topics: [1,2,3,4,5]
```

And something like this

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: consumer-example
  labels:
    app: consumer
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: consumer
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: consumer
    spec:
      containers:
{{ for i, t := range .Values.topics }}
      - name: consumer-{{ i }}
        image: {{ .Values.application.image }}:{{ .Values.application.tag }}
        env:
        - name: KAFKA_TOPIC
          value:  {{ t }} 
{{ end }}
```

Alternatively, you can simply make one application subscribe to multiple topics using multi-threading.

Comment: I don't understand the question. This answer only deploys one pod with many containers. **Containers** can stop any any time, but the Pod can still be running. If the pod stops, then all associated containers will also stop, so all consumers also stop, not only one

Comment: That's exactly what I answered. You can use `consumer.subscribe(System.getEnv("KAFKA_TOPIC"))` in each **container** to read only data from one topic, for each topic in the values array

Comment: Can you please help me on the following issue `{"message":"[Consumer clientId=consumer-XXX, groupId=XXX-stage-XXXX] Topic authorization failed for topics [RK_TEST_TOPIC_TEST]","logger_name":"org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata","thread_name":"KAFKA_LISTENER_ID_CUSTOM_TEST","level":"ERROR","level_value":40000}`

Same data I am getting from terminal (from producer & cosumer) But via code having this issue. Do i need to add the config property of it ?

Comment: You'll need to talk to your cluster administrator to know how to configure client authentication

Comment: Thanks @OneCrickteer for your support, currently I am able to implement differnt topic consuption on different containers . Again thanks

Comment: I have a one query, please help me on it ..That  I am using muliple PODS for the multiple topics, Can we handle same thing in single POD/Container. Like i have 6 topic.. I do not want to create seprate PODS for the same.. Which methodology you recommend to use.. Please guide me on it.  @OneCricketeer

Comment: You can also do that, yes

Comment: Then I need to write multiple consumer in different class for that ?

Comment: No? You can run the exact same class from one pod and many containers, or from many pods, each with one container... Each container can have the same image, and therefore would have the same classes